# Flutter app fails to sign in using firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

My app is working just fine, I configured firebase exactly as per the documentation but when I try to sign is using my email or phone, the debug console output these lines:

```
E/[EGL-ERROR](23198): __egl_platform_cancel_buffers:644: surface->num_buffers(4)
D/Surface (23198): Surface::disconnect(this=0x87e5e800,api=1)
D/GraphicBuffer(23198): unregister, handle(0x8abba6c0) (w:720 h:1344 s:720 f:0x1 u:f02)
D/View    (23198): [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@b80c15a[SignInHubActivity]
D/WindowClient(23198): Remove from mViews: DecorView@b80c15a[SignInHubActivity], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@fa9f256
I/flutter (23198): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
I/flutter (23198): token: eTG1JsOlPsI:APA91bFt25dgB845YX277pu_-NpnvzxMc1N4sCjndQr15S7m0R2jwvqKmdV9-IE0s3aqNECjqaljAg1hmYvm4WaFssHmWITJHdO0NoqGiPziyWeIJE7vgOFMWfGp8kO-uza36euR4ifU
W/DynamiteModule(23198): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(23198): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(23198): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
V/NativeCrypto(23198): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
I/ProviderInstaller(23198): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
I/System.out(23198): port:443
```

There is no exception error message displayed and the login screen just continues to load indefinitely.

I also noticed some warnings note after running "flutter clean" command and relaunch my app but I don't know if they are related to the login failure:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO KA7 in debug mode...
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\device_apps-1.0.9\android\src\main\java\fr\g123k\deviceapps\DeviceAppsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.13.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.6.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\share-0.6.3+6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\share\SharePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\video_player-0.10.8+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\videoplayer\VideoPlayerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

I am new to flutter, but If I get guidance I can try to troubleshoot. Any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Please share your sign in method code. This seems to be a problem : I/flutter (23198): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'. Ignore the warnings on flutter clean.

Comment: Those errors look like they have to do with your view and not the sign in, but I'm not sure. Could you share the source code?